# Cordova - jquery ajax post to php on server

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, cordova

I want to create an token based system, where I want to push the value of an input field to my server side php file to insert it into my database.

Cordova html:

```
<input type="text" class="valueToken" name="usertoken" >
<button class="postToken">PostToken</button>
```

Cordova js:

```
$('.postToken').click(function(){
  console.log($('.valueToken').val());
  var tokenValue = $('.valueToken').val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://domainName.com/fysioWebapp/php/get_token.php",
    data: { 'dataString': tokenValue },
    cache: false,
    success: function(){
        alert("Order Submitted");
    }
});
```

});

And here is my serverside php:

```
<?php
include("connect.php");

$stringData = $_POST['tokenValue']; 
echo $stringData

$insertToken = "INSERT INTO User_Token VALUES ('$stringData')";
$tokenresult = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

 if($tokenresult){
    echo "Successful";
}else {
        echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

?>

But it is not posting the data to my get_token.php file what am I missing here?

With this as error on the cordova side: `POST http://domainName.com/fysioWebapp/php/get_token.php 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: weird stuff... no form ? why input has name `usertoken` and you don't try to use that $var ? plus the $vars you will get is `usertoken`

Comment: @OldPadawan yes don't mind the name in the html. But what do you mean by i dont try to use the $var insteas of html value?

Comment: that's was an error while writing, sorry :/ so I edited. your data passed through Ajax is `usertoken`though

Comment: So use the name of the input instead of get `.val()` in the ajax data:?

Comment: please see answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

500 Internal Server Error will be shown if your php code has fatal errors like syntax errors and error displaying is switched off.

In your php file try adding:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

In .htaccess file add:

```
php_flag display_errors 1
```

Found a similar answer when looking how to debug 500 errors in PHP.

**Original:**

Try this code.

**JS**

```
$('.postToken').click(function(){
   console.log($('.valueToken').val());
   var tokenValue = $('.valueToken').val();

   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url:  "http://domainName.com/fysioWebapp/php/get_token.php",
       data: { dataString: tokenValue },
       cache: false,
       success: function(){
          alert("Order Submitted");
          }
   });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
include("connect.php");

$stringData = $_POST['dataString']; 

echo $stringData

$insertToken = "INSERT INTO User_Token VALUES ('$stringData')";
$tokenresult = mysqli_query($conn, $insertToken);

if($tokenresult){
    echo "Successful";
}else {
    echo "Error description: " .  (mysqli_error($conn));
}
?>
```

Comment: gonna try this now

Comment: same error in the cordova app: `
jquery.min.js:4 POST http://DomainName.com/fysioWebapp/php/get_token.php 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: That webpage doesn't exist. If I copy the URL into a browser it takes me to domainname.com and says page doesn't exist. I suspect you have an error with that as well. Will update my answer with this as well.

Comment: Because DomainName = sylvanreinieren

Comment: oh and btw $tokenresult = mysqli_query($conn, $insertToken)

Comment: Ok will take another look.

Comment: I have edited the PHP code a little bit. I think there was a syntax error in the else statement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141729/discussion-between-l-balsdon-and-sreinieren).

Answer (score 0):

I have put some names/values almost identical to yours, but I make a little difference with Ajax because I'm used to do that way... you'll have to adapt to your needs :)
EDIT: you did *not* get the proper $vars in get_token.php because using wrong name.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#submit").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   console.log($('.valueToken').val());
   var tokenValue = $('.valueToken').val();

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "get_token.php",
        data: "token="+tokenValue,
        success: function(html){ alert(html); }
    });
  });
});
</script>

<form action="#" id="form" method="post">
<input type="text" class="valueToken" name="usertoken" >
<input type="submit" class="postToken" id="submit" value="PostToken" />
</form>
```

/*-- get_token.php --*/

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$token = $_POST['token'];

echo"[ $token ]";

?>
```

Comment: I'll get this error: `Notice: Undefined index: token in /php/get_token.php on line 21`

Comment: @Sreinieren : did you modify anything ? adding something ? just picking some portion of my code to get in yours ? 'cause it works for sure :)

Comment: Nope just copied your code exact, but I make the post from an cordova application to a php on webserver.

Comment: @Sreinieren : `on line 21`how can it be as I have 10 lignes of code ?

Comment: In the mobile app there is no error and it alerts the message value. But when I go to the website with specific get_token.php I'll get that error..

Comment: @Sreinieren : with your own get_token.php with other stuff in it *plus* the query that is ?

Comment: Deleted the other code just pasted your code in get_token.php